# Объясните, как работает это округление числа в большую сторону?

Tags: python

Мне по заданию надо было округлить число в большую сторону, при это не использовав условный оператор и сторонние библиотеки.

Не сумев разобраться самостоятельно, я полез в *google* и нашёл такое решение. Однако проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как это работает.

```
int(-1 * n // 1 * -1)
```

Comment: Это, как в анекдоте, "если выкрутить свечу, какое колесо..." Вот заставить бы того, кто задает такие задания, описать алгоритм работы любого оператора из решения, которое его устроит, без использования условного перехода... Например, целочисленное деление: 1. берем целую часть от деления. И... 2. Если исходное число больше нуля, то; если исходное число меньше нуля, то если дробная часть не равна нулю и т.д. С умножением на -1 тоже засада из 3-х "если", Вообще, ни один более или менее разумный алгоритм не обходится без 3-х китов программизма - последовательности выполнения, ветвления и циклов.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int(-1 * n // 1 * -1)
```

`//` — это оператор целочисленного деления в Python. По приоритету он такой же, как умножение, поэтому выполнение происходит слева направо:

1. Сначала число умножается на -1 (минус один), то есть просто меняется знак числа
2. Затем полученный результат делится на единицу. Это целочисленное деление с округлением вниз, но поскольку мы поменяли знак, то округлять начинает вверх
3. Наконец мы опять умножаем всё на -1, чтобы вернуть знак как было

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> n = 5.3
>>> 
>>> step1 = -1 * n
>>> step1
-5.3
>>> step2 = step1 // 1
>>> step2
-6.0
>>> step3 = step2 * -1
>>> step3
6.0
>>> step4 = int(step3)
>>> step4
6
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

Объяснения выше уже есть, так что считаю рационально рассказать вам о более лёгком методе округления, который легче понять.

```py
o = 1 - int(1 - n % 1) # выясняем, есть ли остаток, ниже будет объяснено подробно
a = n//1 + o # складываем целую часть и остаток, округлённый вверх
```

А теперь подробнее про остаток. Мы отнимает от единицы не целую часть числа, и python автоматически округляет в меньшую сторону. Тем самым, когда остатка нет функция возвращает 1, а когда есть – 0. После этого мы просто переворачиваем результат с помощью операции вычитания.

Надеюсь, информация была полезна. Удачи в изучение Python!